# DataTable and DataSet should be obsolete now?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ado.net, datatable, dataset

Is there any valid use case for DataSet and DataTable now that we have Entity Framework?
Should DataTable/DataSet be considered obsolete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't go as far as calling them obsolete. I still use datasets when gathering data from several different datasources; xml-files, databases, etc. Then I can use `LINQ to DataSet` to manipulate data from the different sources.

I believe there may be other scenarios as well where datasets will be the right fit.

Answer (score 3):

When you know the data schema at compile time then I'd EF would be all you need.  However, there are situation where you're getting data from a service and you don't know what the schema/datatypes will be ahead of time.  I think DataSet/DataTable would still be useful in that kind of scenario.

Answer (score 1):

BulkCopy is one area where DataSets hold a clear advantage over EF.